# How can I determine if a word is a part of an english word or is a portmanteau (a word created by combining parts of valid English words)?

Tags: parsing, nlp, text-processing, linguistics

I am trying to create a validator that takes in words and tries to determine if the word is one of the following:

1. It is a valid English word
2. It is a part of an English word
3. It is an abbreviation
4. It is a portmanteau -- a word created by concatenating parts of valid English words

Are there Java or Python libraries/frameworks that can perform this task?

**Samples of words:**  *meds, ppg, reauthorization, appmetadata, reconsent, rawlog*

I've tried Python NLTK (cursory investigation so far) and a Python library called *enchant* (this fails to identify many valid words/parts of words and portmanteaus).

Comment: You need an English dictionary plus some data extraction. I doubt that anyone else than you wants to specifically identify portemanteaus.

Comment: Over time, some portmanteaus become "valid English words", not because they correspond to some algorithm or other, but just because they get used enough with a particular meaning to make it into the common vocabulary.